# Explicitly writing out the analytic continuation of a real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-continuation

Consider the following function
$$
f(x) = x\cdot h(x) - g(h(x))
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}, f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $f, h, g$ are analytic everywhere and extend to be complex analytic on $\mathbb{C}$

I'm interested in the imaginary component of the continuation of $f$, $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, that is

$$
f(z) = u(x,y) + i\;v(x,y), \quad z = x + iy
$$
where I want to be able to write out $v$ in terms of $g$ and $h$, or at least be able to give some properties of $v$.

I'm not sure why I'm finding this so difficult, presumably because I require extra conditions on $h(x)$ and $g(x)$?  For example, I think (this is somewhere upstream in the overall argument I'm trying to make) I can safely say that $h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

My **question** is therefore - assuming I had extra conditions on the function $g(x)$, how would I go about finding $v(x,y)$ without having an explicit form for $h(x)$ and $g(x)$, and instead just knowing general properties?

Comment: Not every real analytic on $\mathbb R$ extends to be complex analytic on $\mathbb C.$

Comment: Yes, but in this case (again further up in the argument) I know that $f$ does indeed extend to be complex analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.  I shall amend the question to reflect this, thank you for pointing out the oversight

Comment: Is $f$ real on $\mathbb R?$

Comment: Yes. Sorry, clarified again.

Comment: Are $g$ and $h$ analytic as well?

Comment: Oops, I'm not very good at writing these questions.  They are indeed analytic, I have again edited the question to clarify